# How to compare two XSDs file in PHP (XSD 0.1.0 and XSD 0.2.0)

Tags: php, xml, xsd, compare

I know how to compare XML with XSD, but I would like to know how to compare two XSD files. I tried with this code

```
bool compare(string s1, string s2) {
    XmlDocument x1 = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDocument x2 = new XmlDocument();
    x1.Load(s1);
    x2.Load(s2);
    return x1.InnerXml == x2.InnerXml;
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried yourself? Or should we do all the work?

Comment: i tried with this bellow code, but i need efficient code...bool compare(string s1, string s2){
    XmlDocument x1 = new XmlDocument(), x2 = new XmlDocument();
    x1.Load(s1);
    x2.Load(s2);
    return x1.InnerXml == x2.InnerXml;
}

Comment: just edit your question and add the code to it, instead of posting it as a comment

Comment: is it possible to compare to  two xsd file using php?

Comment: **Define *compare***:  (1) Lexically identical? (2) Lexically identical after being placed in canonical XML form? or, (3) Accepting identical XML documents?  Because: (1) is too simple to be asking here; (2) is reasonable but of questionable value; (3) is too broad to be asking here, but please publish if you do as it'd be very impressive.

Comment: @davejal please solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

XSD files **are** XML files (just ones that follow the XSD schema), so as long as you know how to compare XML, you also know how to compare XSD. The more important question is what you want to achieve. If you want to compare the schemas, then comparing them on the level of XML will not give very useful results. In the end, you then want to know and compare which types and elements and attributes are defined in the schemas, i suppose. If that's what you want to do, you should not just compare them as XML files, that would not be a good solution to the problem.

Comment: Yes, but is there any possibility to do XSD comparison in PHP

Comment: but what exactly do you mean by that? just compare them on the XML level? if so, just use the method you're using for all XML files.

Comment: Please forget about XML files, and give me suggestion to compare two XSDs

Comment: that's a hard thing to do, if you want to compare the XSD on the XSD level, i.e. compare them according to their schema components. there are commercial tools for doing that (http://www.altova.com/diffdog/xml-schema-diff-tool.html, just as one example), but even there it's not easy to quantify just how exactly two schemas are differing. it would help a lot if you could say what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: i would like to compare two large XSD, manually it's difficult so i would like to write program for that.